# Powershell Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Not "seeing" PPP Adapter

Tags: ip, scripting, powershell

I am trying to get the IP of a PPP VPN network connection, but Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration does not seem to "see" it.

If I interrogate all adapters using my script, it will see everything but the PPP VPN adapter. Is there a specific filter or something I need to enable, or do I need a different class?

My Script:

```
$colItems = Get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
foreach ($objItem in $colItems) {
    Write-Host Description: $objItem.Description
    Write-Host IP Address: $objItem.IPAddress
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Script Output:

```
Description: WAN Miniport (SSTP)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (L2TP)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (PPTP)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (IPv6)
IP Address:

Description: WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
IP Address:

Description: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
IP Address: 192.168.2.5

Description: WAN Miniport (IP)
IP Address:
```

ipconfig /all output:

```
PPP adapter My VPN:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : My VPN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.8.12(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3
                                       10.1.1.2
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.2
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 10.1.1.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled



Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Belkin
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-3F-3C-22-22-22
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.5(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 25 May 2010 20:33:19
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 22 May 2020 20:33:17
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: get a copy of MoW's powershell script "WMI Explorer". As the name implies, it is a GUI for exploring WMI. His blog where I would normally download it seems to be down, but this technet site has a copy of it: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/89c759b7-20b4-49e8-98a8-3c8fbdb2dd69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a very old thread, still I'll post the way I manage it so it could help someone like me, as I couldn't find a ready solution.

What this does is loop through several hosts and their NICs. It shows ALL NIC IPs but not a default one.

```
Get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter IPEnabled=TRUE -computername localhost,127.0.0.1 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Write-Host Server: $_.__SERVER
    Write-Host Adapter name: $_.Description
    Write-Host IP Addresses: $_.IPAddress
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549091) that was present in Vista and hasn't gotten fixed through Windows 7 or Windows 8. You have to call the .NET API directly from Powershell to get this information.

```
$nics = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
foreach ($nic in $nics) {
    write-host $nic.name
    $props = $nic.GetIPProperties()
    $addresses = $props.UnicastAddresses
    foreach ($addr in $addresses) {
        write-host "IP Address: $($addr.Address.IPAddressToString)"
        write-host "IPv4 Mask: $($addr.IPv4Mask.IPAddressToString)"
    }
    write-host "Gateway: $($props.GatewayAddresses.Address.IPAddressToString)"
    write-host "DNS Server(s): $($props.DnsAddresses.IPAddressToString)"
    write-host ""
}
```

See also [the NetworkInterface class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the MSFT_NetIPAddress class instead.

Powershell Example:

```
gwmi MSFT_NetIPAddress -Namespace 'root/standardcimv2' | format-list -Property InterfaceAlias,IPAddress
```

Comment: This is the only method to look up a VNP "PPP adapter" of Windows 10. When _connection is established_, the adapter is present (as listed with DOS command `IPConfig`) and `InterfaceAlias` holds the name it was given in Windows. When the _connection is down_, the adapter is gone, thus will not be listed.